# Client-Server comunication on the same android device

Tags: java, android, server, client

What address do I have to use for the creation of the client if I run it on the same device as the server.

```
Client client=new Client(something,port);
                             ^
                             |
                        What has to stay there
```

I tried with "localhost" and "10.0.2.2" but it didnt work

Comment: `127.0.0.1`, sweet `127.0.0.1`...

Comment: isn't this the same as localhost @adjan

Comment: I have no idea what IP format etc. your `Client` class expects, nor where you got it from.

Comment: I use Java's Client class @adjan

Comment: what's the point of using sockets on the sane host if you can use pipes?

Comment: I want to make the thing multiplayer where one pleyer creates the server and joins it and the other join it. @pskink